# Dashicons in wordpress (frontend) won't display

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I'm creating a website in WordPress. I'm using dashicons for rating (manually) holidays.

It used to work, but after update the dashicons won't be visible for non-logged in users. Only, if you login, you can see the star ratings.

The star rating should be visible on the left top of each holiday deal.

Who knows a solution?

Website url is [www.ikwilopvakantie.nl](http://www.ikwilopvakantie.nl)

Answer (score 34):

[Dashicons is the official icon font of the WordPress admin as of 3.8.](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/).

To load Dashicons for non logged in users:

1. Open directory `{your-website-folder/wp-content/themes/}`
2. Go into the folder of your active child theme ( if you don't have active child theme, open the folder of your active parent theme )
3. Find there `functions.php` file and add the provided code at the end of it (
   make sure, there isn't `?>` php closing tag at the end of file. if so, just remove it ):

   ```
    function ww_load_dashicons(){
        wp_enqueue_style('dashicons');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ww_load_dashicons');
   ```
4. Save changes. Dashicons will loads on your website for all users.

**EDIT**: there may be some plugin/code, which removed Dashicons from pages. Try to change your code with this one:

```
function ww_load_dashicons(){
   wp_enqueue_style('dashicons');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ww_load_dashicons', 999);
```

Comment: Hi The code is already in my functions.php file (i already added this). But still the same issue...

Comment: Humm still nothing, i see the square signs instead of the star dashicon...

Comment: you have some cache plugin in your website. clear all cache from plugin, also, clear cache from browser

Comment: Yep, i deleted all cache in website and cloudflare. Im also using firefox private browser with the setting to don't cache websites... But nothing happens... Do you still see the squares of do you see the stars (top left of a block)

Comment: your cache plugin is still active. delete all cache and deactivate it/remove all settings. can you confirm, that the provided code still in the functions.php file of active theme?

Comment: I am having the same problem in version 5.0.

Comment: @Xarcell did you try provided answer?

Comment: My problem was I was using my own HTML, and forgot to add the dashicons font-family to it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<span class="bx-next dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span>
```

'dashicons-arrow-right-alt2' is the class of the icon.
You can find them here: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#arrow-up-alt

This has to go to your functions.php file:

```
function load_dashicons(){
    wp_enqueue_style('dashicons');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_dashicons');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was simply that my browser blocker addons weren't allowing the source of dashicons.css

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the plug-in "Asset CleanUp", you can navigate to "BULK CHANGES" and easily use "Remove site-wide rule" at the line, where the url for "dashicon" is listed.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the icons on the [official list](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/) were appearing blank for me when  defined as a value of the `menu-item` property in the `register_post_type` function.

If you open `wp-includes/css/dashicons.css` you will see a complete list of icons available, many of which have different names, for example `dashicons-quote` is actually `dashicons-editor-quote`.

Using these values solved the problem for me. I also found this [cheat sheet](https://lonewolfonline.net/wordpress-dashicons-cheat-sheet/) to be helpful if you don't want to go digging through your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me— For some reason, dashicons was only not rendering when I wasn't accessing the https:// version of the site.